# How to configure JPA with JPQL in Spring Boot Application - "can't resolve symbol.."

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, jpql

I have a dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

Configuration for JPA is inside **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pass
...
```

When I create ***@Entity:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cats")
public class Cat {
    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;
    ....
}
```

It works well. When i try to use ***JPQL***:

```
"select cat from Cat cat"
```

Intellij idea emphasizes it and says ***"Can't resolve symbol Cat"***, I click *more* ***"This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked"***.
It's worth saying it works correctly *without errors* and *exceptions*.

To solve it, somebody recommend in ***Intellij***:

***Project structure - facets - add - JPA***.
After it Intellij ***stop*** to show this warning near ***JPQL*** syntax, but ***starts*** to show warnings near *@Column(name="name")* and *@Table(name="cats")* in my ***Entity.class***.

How to configure JPA ***not to get this warnings neither in JPQL nor in Entity.class***?

Comment: You aren't configuring "JPA", you are configuring Intellij. Suggest that you actually tag `Intellij` on this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
"select cat from " + Cat.class.getName() + " cat"
```

This solution is quite good, because whenever you rename class `Cat`, intellij will rename it inside jpql query as well.

Comment: It works and i think it's better than it was, but it must be possible to configure it correctly and use without such tricks)

Comment: That is not a hack. You are passing a class name, just as the jpql requires. There must be more than one class named Cat, so you must be precise. This has nothing to do with intellij.

Comment: Oh, ty, you are right. Class name Cat is just for an example. Actual class name is the same as one another class from standard java classes