# Hibernate Query parent based on different subtype properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a HQL query which selects all of the `Parent` entities, based on two different properties which exist on child entities.

```
abstract class Parent {
  int id;
  String type;
}

class ChildOne extends Parent {
  Colour colour;
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
  Size size;
}
```

My working query looks like this: `SELECT p FROM Parent p LEFT JOIN p.colour c LEFT JOIN p.size s WHERE c.shade = 'RED' OR s.width = 15`.

This query does work fine, but of course it gives me warnings about `colour` and `size` not existing on `Parent` in my join statements. How can I fix it so that I do not get these warnings?

The warning messages that I get is: `Can't resolve symbol 'colour'` and `Can't resolve symbol 'size'`.

Comment: I do not get why you have `List<ChildOne>` in `Parent` and `ChildOne extends Parent`. Do you want `ChildOne` to inherit `List<ChildOne>` and `List<ChildTwo>`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `List<ChildXXX>` aren't supposed to be there. I will remove them!

Comment: You could probably use MappedSuperClass(https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#mappedsuperclass), but that will require two calls to DB.

Comment: I don't think I can use @MappedSuperClass because my project already has different tables for the child tables.

Comment: You mean to say, you have different tables for `Parent`, `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`? If yes, then how what inheritance mapping are you using currently?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure JPA with JPQL in Spring Boot Application - "can't resolve symbol.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851818/how-to-configure-jpa-with-jpql-in-spring-boot-application-cant-resolve-symbo)

Comment: @SternK No it does not answer my question. It is the `LEFT JOIN p.colour` and so on which gives me the warning. I have my datasources correctly set up so that `Parent` resolves just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue and get rid of the warnings by using the following query:

```
SELECT p FROM Parent p
LEFT JOIN ChildOne c1 on p = c1
LEFT JOIN ChildTwo c2 on p = c2
WHERE c1.shade = 'RED' OR c2.width = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are seeing IntelliJ or Eclipse warnings? You can't get rid of them. Also, this is a HQL or Hibernate specific feature. In plain JPQL you have to use the `TREAT` operator to access subtype properties, but no JPA implementation gets this right i.e. they introduce type constraint predicates that are semantically wrong. Hibernate 6.0 will fix this, but for now, I would recommend you use the query you already have and ignore the warnings.

Comment: I see the warnings in the Hibernate Console and within IntelliJ inside of a repository `@Query()`. Is there a bug or some kind of ticket where Hibernate acknowledges this problem?

Comment: There is no bug. Not sure what you are looking for. This is simply a feature of Hibernate that tools can't validate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` on Parent class

Comment: I have this on my `Parent` class, but I still get `Can't resolve symbol` warnings.